# Delete array results already shown

Tags: php, arrays

I have a numbered array like this

```
array(60) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(6) "test" ["slug"]=> string(6) "test" } }
```

And I get only 10 results from it in the first foreach and store the 'id's for later exclusion based on that **(not sure if I'm doing it right)**, how do I delete these first 10 results in a second foreach?

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($i <= 10) {                      
       //do something
       $exclude[] = $row['id'];
    }
    $i++;  
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you show us the expected outcome? What is it you're actually trying to achieve? Do you want to actually _delete_ elements from the array after having processed them, or do you just want to avoid processing them again in a subsequent `foreach()` - i.e. you want to process your array in batches of 10?

Comment: @jibsteroos I wish not to show in the second foreach the first 10 results already shown in the first foreach.

Comment: I would suggest the more concise `foreach($array as $i=>$row)`. Then, if you really must delete the array member you could `unset($array[$i])` as part of the first foreach. I personally don’t like to using a non-authoritative index like this, I’d rather craft the array to use a database table’s primary id if I need to refer to a specific row. For that matter, I’d also question why it needs to be deleted...

Comment: how is your second/third/... `foreach()` different? Does the functionality change per batch of 10 'records'? Why not process all 60 'records' in one loop in batches of 10, possibly with a different logic applied to each batch?

Comment: Basically I have two columns on a website and in the first column I show the first 10 results so in the second I would like not to repeat the ones already shown. Escape would be the most correct!? So how do you do that?

Comment: [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#99607)

Comment: I don't think that applies in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Basically it looks like this:

```
$ids = array_column($array, 'id');
$new_list = array_diff($ids, $exclude);
```

Now just use '$new_list' in the second foreach.